# Simplifying loops over hashmap values

Tags: java, hashmap

I have the following code:

```
public void setSHAShortSha() {
        if (parentTracked == null) {
            String s = "";
            for (Blob b : blobHashMap.values()) {
                s += b.toString();
            }
            sha = Utils.sha1(logMessage + dateFormatted + s);
        } else {
            String s = "";
            for (Blob b : blobHashMap.values()) {
                s += b.toString();
            }
            for (Blob b : parentTracked.values()) {
                s += b.toString();
            }
            sha = Utils.sha1(logMessage + dateFormatted + s);
        }
        shortSha = MyUtils.getShortSha(sha);
    }
```

This looks a lot complex. Could there be a simpler way to write it in java?

```
 boolean found = false;
        for (Commit commit : commits.values()) {
            if (commit.getLogMessage().compareTo(commitMessageToSearch) == 0) {
                System.out.println(commit.getSha());
                found = true;
            }
        }
        if (!found) {
            System.out.println("aksdhlkasj");
        }
```

Adding one more code as that is on the same lines. I am little unfamiliar with different forms of for loop and streams need help converting them

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can join all of the values with streams:

```
s += blobHashMap.values().stream().map(Object::toString).collect(Collectors.joining());
```

Comment: That's cool. I will remember this. If you could assist me with one more code, that would be great. I have added to the main question

Answer (score 2):

You can at least avoid the repetition.

```
public void setSHAShortSha() {
    String s = "";
    for (Blob b : blobHashMap.values()) {
        s += b.toString();
    }
    if (parentTracked != null) {
        for (Blob b : parentTracked.values()) {
            s += b.toString();
        }
    }
    sha = Utils.sha1(logMessage + dateFormatted + s);
    shortSha = MyUtils.getShortSha(sha);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the forEach Method of the Map, like this:

```
StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    blobHashMap.forEach((key, blob) -> {
        stringBuilder.append(blob.toString());
    });
    if (parentTracked != null) {
        parentTracked.forEach((key, blob) -> {
            stringBuilder.append(blob.toString());
        });
    }
    sha = Utils.sha1(logMessage + dateFormatted + stringBuilder.toString());
    shortSha = MyUtils.getShortSha(sha);
}
```

Comment: If you're not using `key`, you can do `blobHashMap.values().forEach(blob -> ...)` instead.

Comment: correct, left it in to show that you can use it, if you needed it.